# ZOHO CRM - Does it support JSON Posts?

Tags: zoho

I'm playing around and evaluation CRM systems and came across ZOHO.  All the examples I have seen post XML to the APi methods.  I'm wondering if ZOHO supports JSON posts and any examples there may be

Answer (score 0):

Zoho CRM API don't support neither JSON nor XML in requests in native way.

Zoho CRM API expect application/www-x-form-urlencoded request with parameter xmlData that contains XML.
Here is [Development Console](https://apigee.com/i.vatsenko/embed/console/zoho-crm)

BR Igor